# Use of a preposition

Tags: prepositions

[image]

In the image posted, what preposition fits best?

A. The boy is passing *through* a house.

B. The boy is passing *in front of* a house.

C. The boy is passing *past* a house.

Actually what I know about the use of 'through' is that it refers to the move from one side of an object to the other.

As for, 'in front of' I feel it is used in states e.g. the boy is standing in front of a house.

To me, 'past' seems to be the best choice here.

Question: Which one to be used A, B or C?

Comment: We would never say 'passing past'. Use 'walking past' or just 'passing'. (By the way, there is only one boy in the picture so 'boys' is wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

- *Through X* means you at some point are "in" X or surrounded by X.  So you can't go through a house unless you enter it.  You can go through a yard by crossing its borders or fences.
- In the picture, we do see the front of the house, but the house is sort of angled.  The phrase "in front of a house" is likely to evoke someone walking past the front yard, along a sidewalk or front fence.  However it wouldn't be totally wrong to say *walk in front of* this house.
- Moving *past X* simply means moving in such a way that X will be behind you at some point.  This definitely applies.

*Past* is the best choice.

I would be more concerned about the cactus he's going to walk into though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd not opt for *through* here to avoid the ambiguity it brings. See the [meanings here.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pass+through)

On the other hand, *passing in front of...* could be a choice because a boy is passing and then there's a house in the background. I'm not sure about 'past' a house because I have never come across such usage.

But, I'd naturally call this with the ***combination*** of those phrases as stated [in McMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pass-by) -

> *A car slowly **passed by the front of the** house.*

Comment: The trouble with _through_ is worse than ambiguity: it means the boy will _enter_ the house, walk _through_ it, and then exit. "Past" also works in other sentences like "The boy is walking past the house." But since the verb is already _passing_, "in front of" is the best option.

Comment: @TypeIA interesting to note that my example has no *in!*

Comment: Your example, while otherwise fine, is also not one of the three given multiple-choice options.

Comment: @TypeIA I talked about those three and **then** gave the correct one, the one I'd choose.

Comment: We seem to have a misunderstanding. I'm not criticizing your example. I'm pointing out the understatement in your evaluation of the first option, and augmenting your answer by noting that _of the three original options_, "in front of" is the best.